# How to write query to find data in nested and not nested fields together

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I would like to find multiple field search.

So:

```
GET my_doc/_search
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match" : {
      "query":    "text", 
      "fields": [ "state", "city"] 
    }
  }
}
```

Generally **this query works**, but it does **not** search in the **nested** fields.

But this one works only for nested fields:

```
GET my_doc*/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "images",
            "score_mode": "max", 
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {"match": {"images.description": "Subject" }},
                  {"match": {"images.Number": "10004" }}
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

My question is:

How to write query to search **everywhere**  - Just to **join** my queries together to find in the **"images"** location too.

Answer (score 0):

I've found solution, just to join queries:

```
 GET my_doc*/_search
    {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "multi_match" : {
                "query":    "LAKE", 
                "fields": [ "state", "city"] 
              }
            },

            {
              "nested": {
                "path": "images",
                "score_mode": "max", 
                "query": {
                  "bool": {
                    "must": [
                       {"match": {"images.description": "Subject" }},
                       {"match": {"images.Number": "10004" }}
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
```